# Mongo DB $regex operation

Tags: mongodb

I have a string value in my database

```
dob: 2017-09-10 12:00:00
```

I tried `find({dob : "2017-09-10 00:00:00"})` - did not return any result (expected)

Then I tried `find({dob:{$regex : "2017-09-10", "$options": "i"}})` - it returned the above record even though I did not include any pattern search.

Please help me understand why.

Comment: `00:00:00` is not the same as `12:00:00` and therefore is not a match.

Comment: But why did it return result for -  find({dob:{$regex : "2017-09-10", "$options": "i"}}.. That is where I got confused. Because as per docs it is - /pattern/ : { name: { $in: [ /^acme/i, /^ack/ ] } }

Comment: Using [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) as an "operator" explicitly "implies" a pattern search for the string presented. And there are extensive examples in teh documentation. So either `{ dob: { $regex: "2017--09-10" } }` or `{ dob: /2017-09-10/ }` are actually the same thing. As long as you are in a JavaScript shell that is. Which is why `$regex` exists as an operator, so it works with **all** language implementations.

Comment: Thank you.. That makes sense.